# Rename value output and combine value in one column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that list athletes and the sports they play or don't play.  I would like to have the results value to list in one column.

```
   SELECT    Ind_First_Name, Ind_Last_Name,
             CASE WHEN Baseball = 'Y' THEN 'Baseball |' ELSE '' END+ ' ' +
             CASE WHEN Football = 'Y' THEN 'Football |' ELSE '' END+ ' ' +
             CASE WHEN Soccer = 'Y' THEN 'Soccer' ELSE '' END

   from      Sports
```

I would like to see the output to be: (Given that Football has a 'N')
Jane  Doe  Baseball | Soccer

My output keeps putting an empty space.  Not sure how to remove that space with the Football value is blank.

Comment: What happens if they only play Baseball? Then you'll have a pipe at the end, is this acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Put the space inside the Case Statement.

**UPDATED**  Removed pipes and spaces.

```
SELECT    Ind_First_Name, Ind_Last_Name,
             CASE WHEN Baseball = 'Y' THEN 'Baseball' ELSE '' END  +
             CASE WHEN Football = 'Y' AND Baseball = 'Y' THEN ' | Football' 
                  WHEN Football = 'Y' AND Baseball = 'N' THEN 'Football' ELSE '' END  +
             CASE WHEN Soccer = 'Y' AND (Football = 'Y' OR Baseball = 'Y') THEN ' | Soccer'                             
                  WHEN Soccer = 'Y' AND Baseball = 'N' AND Football = 'N' THEN 'Soccer' ELSE '' END    
   from      Sports
```

Comment: There are flaws in that if they only play Baseball, that would have a hanging pipe on the end.

Comment: So I'm not sure how to set it up so that the pipe is not shown if nothing follows.  My output for when only Soccer is yes is:

Comment: So I'm not sure how to set it up so that the pipe is not shown if nothing follows.  My output for when only Soccer is yes is: "  Soccer" as apposed to having: "Soccer".  The proceeding empty space is inputted.  Not sure if an iCount= would work nor am I sure how to program it.  I'll keep working on it and try different options.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT    Ind_First_Name, Ind_Last_Name,
         CASE WHEN Baseball = 'Y' THEN 'Baseball | ' ELSE '' END +
         CASE WHEN Football = 'Y' THEN 'Football | ' ELSE '' END +
         CASE WHEN Soccer = 'Y' THEN 'Soccer' ELSE '' END

from      Sports
```